# How to record a video automatically with an embedded system

Tags: linux, video, home-automation, script, bash

I have this project in mind, where I'm not yet sure if it's possible to realize this way.

**The situation**

I want to run an embedded System (for example, a Raspberry, or any other embedded system) to record a Video. The trick is, the controller shall weekly start the recording automatically (ca. 1 h) and save the clip.

Personally I can imagine a Linux system, which is programmed with simple Bash-scripts (e.g. as Init-Scripts) to automate the situation.

**My questions are**

**1)** Is it possible, without too much expense (for example, if it's possible to skip picking apart camera and controller) to control the camera  (or camera module) with the embedded system e.g. by GPIOs?

**2)** Would such a system/concept be reliable or rather robust enough for just putting it in place and it'll run forever, to record and save a video every week. Or am I forced to observe it, to be sure that it's doing its job?

I'll gladly take any further hints about the general concept. Right now I'd like to get an overview if this would be develop-able before I spent too much money.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1) Is it possible

Yes.  The pi has a [CSI-2](http://mipi.org/specifications/camera-interface) ribbon connector and the best way to do this is probably using the that with the 5 megapixel "raspicam" made specifically for it.  They're about $25.  It seems you can [connect other CSI-2 compliant cameras](http://www.petervis.com/Raspberry_PI/Raspberry_Pi_CSI/Raspberry_Pi_CSI_Camera_Module.html), but I would do your homework first as you may end up needing to write a driver for it.

You could also use a USB camera, but make sure that has a linux driver first.

> 2) Would such a system/concept be reliable

Sure.  If configured properly, etc., they will run 24/7 indefinitely.  However, while it *might* be that you could leave one somewhere, forget about it, and come back a year later to find it did everything you wanted and continues to, this implies a pretty high level of confidence that is probably only justified if you actually work with and test your setup sufficiently first.  What that means exactly is up to you.

If at all plausible, it would obviously be preferable to have some kind of network access to check on it from time to time.

Comment: thanks! Well it is actually intended to upload these videos to a web server. I've heard that sometimes these Raspberries get into a dead-lock without a specific reason (which would be the opposite of a robust system), can this happen only for some special tasks? Or wouldn't this happen if you keep a nice amount of system resources.

Comment: I got my first pi about two years ago and now have three, at least one of which is on all the time, sometimes for weeks or months before I reboot it for some reason.  I can't recall any of them "getting into a dead-lock without a specific reason". *However*, I have a lot of prior linux and programming experience.  Many people get into the pi without that and -- understandably -- often quickly run into mysterious seeming problems.  It is not something your average computer owner is going to consider user friendly.  Many of these mysterious unsolved problems online (including here)...

Comment: ...I believe could be diagnosed and solved by someone *on location*.  There is a limit to what can be done casually via the web, unfortunately.  I'm sure I could spend all day in chat with people meticulously working through things, but that is usually very inefficient and of course, I can't afford to be doing that (nor would me alone be sufficient in many cases).  So, there's no 24/7 paid help desk for the pi, and while there are lots of good resources online, you are on your own beyond a certain point.  For some people it's a great gadget, but (as with many other things)...

Comment: ...if your experience level does not match your aspirations, it can no doubt be very, very frustrating.  By analogy, simply having the right toolkit and the shop manual does not mean it is going to be ultimately feasible for you to repair anything on your car (although it is surprising how many things can be, if you have the patience, etc).  So I'm not trying to discourage anyone, just warning them to be realistic in their expectations project wise.  That *somebody* put a lander on a comet, etc., does not mean now just anyone can do it by following a simple recipe.

Comment: Thanks for the warning. I think I'm pretty good with linux hacking, so this shouldn't be a problem. My only concern is just: I don't have much experience with a Raspberry and I'd like to know, if I program the device correctly will it work just as expected or would it be more like workaround after workaround. Because I'm developing for someone else and if I hand it out, for sure I'd like to give it away as some kind of a black box, where the user shouldn't care about that much anymore.

Comment: I can't promise there won't have to be certain fail-safe workarounds in this case; I have a raspicam but I've never left it shooting video over an hour. I do have an I2C device that seems very susceptible to minute power fluctuations; if I wanted it left on continuously, I'd need to work around that by checking it intermittently and restarting the relevant application. The pi itself is pretty sound, but I don't think it's industrial grade -- it's a *development* board. People have put them 40+ km into the atmosphere with balloons, submerged them running in liquid nitrogen, etc, but as to how..

Comment: ...reliably that could be done time after time, who's to know?  Do as much digging as you can, I guess.  In the end, worst comes to worst after proper testing you're out some time (and maybe < $100, but you can still keep the hardware for something else).  That's just how R&D is.  Chances are no matter how you do this it's going to be on a linux based device, so your software will still be good.

Comment: sounds like I'll have to spent the money and then see what comes around, well at least this equipment isn't that expensive. Would you recommend other, more reliable boards for my purpose?

Comment: I'm didn't mean it was unreliable. I meant 1) It's not in widespread industrial use and wasn't intended for such, and 2) It's not certified by anyone for any particular purpose (beyond the manufacturer's warranty against defects, etc.).  Anything that fulfills those two criteria and matches the specs of the pi will probably cost *a lot* more (think 10x).  There's a bewildering array of small specialized boards, if you search around you'll find distributors like [this](http://microcontrollershop.com/). Not my area of expertise tho.

Comment: Well, talking about price difference of 10x is a big thing. I think I'll post around the pricey forums and then make a synthesis.

Comment: I feel bad for discouraging you, lol.  Chances are the pi would be as good as anything else here, and there's the benefit of a relatively large public user base. That last pure guestimate might be a slight exaggeration -- but e.g., [here's ~5x](http://www.embeddedarm.com/products/board-detail.php?product=TS-7250-V2).  Found that via [this free-electrons page](http://free-electrons.com/community/hardware/boards/), which is sort of interesting...

Comment: ...I've definitely seen people flogging similar things for over $1000 U.S. -- although I'm not an electrical engineer and my idea of what "similar" is is limited to basic specs and what I/O there is.

Comment: That's actually why I first thought about the Raspberry. If someone else wants to repair or enhance the system, it'll be a lot easier with such a big user support

Comment: Well as far as I've found out I have 3 options in total to capture a video with the Pi. 1) With the CSI-Interface 2) By the USB-Port 3) Developing an own driver. But I really want to leave out option 3) because of the (unnecessary  (?)) amount of work I have to put in and I think in the end I'm the only one who is able to fix it if there are problems. So theres only 1) & 2) and as far as I've seen the "best" cam is a module with 8 MP, where I'm not sure if this is a sufficient quality. I guess I won't get away without making a step into the dark and just chose the cheap or expensive solution